# Scripts not recognizing Ajax response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to import a view returning a chunk of html to be placed in the body of my document.

```
async('get_user_data',data, function(response){
        /** Response success **/
        $('.stage').html(response.html);

    }, function(response) {
        /** Response error **/
        alert('Error');

        });
```

The `response.html` data that is being placed in the document has scripts that are needed for functionality. Once the data has been imported the scripts don't recognize the new chunk of html.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: can you provide some link or jsfiddle demo?

Comment: It's quite a bit of code but this is all I needed. `$.ajax({url:"http://link"});`